# Set-theoretic definition of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I am trying to understand the set theoretic definition of functions along with its informal one, and would appreciate your comments.

Firstly, Given sets $A$ and $B:$

**Relations:** Any subset of $A \times B,$ that is $R \subseteq A \times B.$

When an ordered pair $(a,b)$ from $A \times B$ belongs to $R$, i.e. $(a,b) \in R$, then we write $a R b$ -- pronounced as $a$ is related to $b$ under $R$

**Functions:** *Relations* with special properties as follows:

1. Each $a \in A$ is related to at least one $b \in B$ under $F.$ That is, for each $a \in A,$ there exists at least one $b \in B$ to which $a$ is related under $F$. In Quantifiers : For each $a \in A, \exists b \in B$ such that their ordered pair $(a,b) \in F.$
2. Each $a \in A$ is related to at most one $b \in B$ under $F.$ That is, for each $a \in A,$ there exists at most one $b \in B$ to which $a$ is related under $F.$

Together we have,

Each $a \in A$ is related to one and only one $b \in B$ under $F.$ That is, for each $a \in A,$ there exists one and only one $b \in B$ to which $a$ is related under $F.$ In Quantifiers : For each $a \in A, \exists! b \in B$ such that their ordered pair $(a,b) \in F.$

We can also simply say that $F \subseteq A \times B$ is a function if, and only if, $F$ contains exactly one ordered pair $(a,b)$ for each $a$.

Also,

**Function (Informal)** : A function from set $A$ to set $B,$ written as $f: A\to B,$ is an assignment which assigns to each element of $A$, exactly one element of $B.$ Meaning, for each $a \in A,$ there exists exactly one $b \in B$ which is assigned to $a$ by $f.$

$f(a)$ simply means the element of $B$ assigned to $a$ by $f.$

In Quantifiers: $\forall a \in A, \exists! b \in B,$ such that $b$ is assigned to $a$ by $f,$ that is $b=f(a)$

Would be great if you could assure me the veracity of my understanding.

I have another question: Why do books always define ideas a bit differently ? Is it really a matter of preference or some other advantage ? Like one book simply defined $F \subseteq A \times B$ a function iff $Dom(F)=A$ and $(a,b) \land (a,c) \in F \implies b=c.$ I know that these two conditions also establish the same idea, but I was just wondering, like when a person tries to understand a new concept for the first time, one may come across authors defining the supposed fundamental ideas slightly differently, but still equivalently.

Comment: A downvote is a surreptitious act; it doesn't add an iota; better leave an instructive comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote this but your post is rather long and I know I don't need a redefinition of functions to suit the needs of someone who is not sure if they understand functions. I hope that doesn't sound too harsh; it might be that the downvote was for a different reason. Perhaps you could focus your question to ask something specific.

Comment: @JohnDouma I really didn't tweak per say, maybe it was a bad introductory phrase. The post is really about clarifying function definition understanding.

Comment: That opening phrase is what motivated my comment. You can ask specific questions about function definitions without establishing everything you know. It is enough to say that  you were given a definition, stating what it is, and then asking for clarification on a piece of it. Resolving two different definitions is also a valid topic for a question.

Comment: Your last question is odd. Books are written by authors. It's a bit like asking why two chefs prepare the same dish slightly differently. It's partly a matter of taste.

Comment: @blargoner Yeah, I was just wondering. Would be great if you could comment on my understanding as in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you wrote looks good to me.

Maybe not really an answer on "why" in general, but a note on this particular difference between these two definitions of function:

The symbol $\operatorname{Dom}$ is just a representation of the same idea that given an $a$ there exists a $b$ with $(a,b) \in F$, expressed as a set of $a$ values rather than a predicate on variable $a$. If the text has already introduced $\operatorname{Dom}$ (because it will be useful again), might as well use it in the definition of function.

Your first definition has "for each $a \in A$, there exists one and only one $b \in B$ to which $a$ is related under $F$", or using predicates, $\forall a \in A, \exists! b \in B, (a,b) \in F$. Your second definition has $(a,b) \in F \land (a,c) \in F \implies b = c$. This is implicitly universally quantified, actually saying: $\forall a \forall b \forall c, (a,b) \in F \land (a,c) \in F \implies b = c$.

But in formal predicate logic, the quantifier $\exists!$ is actually an abbreviation. For a predicate $P$ of one free variable, the notation $\exists! v, P(v)$ means exactly:

$$ (\exists x, P(x)) \land (\forall x \forall y, P(x) \land P(y) \implies x=y) $$

(This uses only fundamental predicate logic. Attempts to interpret "exactly one" or "only one" in the most literal way using a count of elements satisfying the predicate would be more complicated or impossible, presumes an understanding of at least natural numbers, etc.)

So the statement $(a,b) \in F \land (a,c) \in F \implies b=c$ is just writing out the "at most one" piece of the $\exists!$ idea in a standard way.

Then the first definition is one small abstraction away from the most fundamental predicate logic definition by use of the abbreviation $\operatorname{Dom}$; the second definition is one small abstraction away by use of the symbol $\exists!$. I'd call these differences just "rephrases" of essentially the same ideas. I suppose the sameness might not be obvious at first, and part of this is how familiar the reader is with the tools and conventions being used to state the ideas.

Of course, beyond this example, some differences between texts might be similar "rephrases". Some could involve a less trivial reason for equivalence of related statements. Some could introduce ideas in a different order, which requires different justifications or proofs entirely, even when the results are the same. There are different degrees of similarity in exactly what's being said and how it's being presented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Great that you expanded on the subtlety behind different, but equivalent, definitions. I just wanted to confirm my understanding of function's set definition, so is my understanding fine ?

Answer (score 0):

It is comfortable and useful to think about functions as assignments which map x $\in X$ to y $\in Y$. But it is not a formal definition, because we don't know that word "assignment" means.

But we know word "set" means, because you can formally define sets using Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory. Of course you can say that this is not constructive but axiomatic way where you just define sets us mathematical objects which satisfies axioms of ZFC. But i guess we can not make a foundation of mathematics without axioms in which we just believe. If you take a Mathematical logic course you will know more about means of set's definition.

So usually if we have function like $f(x)=x^2 : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ we can say that this fucntion maps $3$ to $9$ and $2$ to $4$ and in head mentally match graph of function and the action which function "does" like we have no difference between these constructions.
But sometimes in more difficult tasks such as proving some properties of function you need to think about it in set terms. Are functions $f(x)=x^2 : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=x^2 : \mathbb{R_+} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ equal if they have the same "assignement's law"? No, because they have different domains.

If this is a first time when you meet with functions, don't think about them much. Because even the formal procedure of defining cartesian product of $n$ sets (you need this to define functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$) is so troublesome and not easy understandable. Mathematics is about doing, so when you will do more tasks, read more books and so you can come back to formal definitions and think about "Why are they such and not others" and where is more useful to think about them using the first way and where you need to use formal rigorous definitions.